# how to sign up to parse.com with profile picture in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to sign up with parse.com user , I tried signup firstly with parsefile (profilePicture) but I got exception "java.lag.illegalStateException: Unable to encode an unsaved parsefile" with this code ,

```
final ParseUser UserObject = new ParseUser();
UserObject.setUsername(userModel.getUsername());
UserObject.setEmail(userModel.getEmail());
UserObject.setPassword(userModel.getPassword());
UserObject.put("Mobile_Number",userModel.getMobile_Number());
UserObject.put("Name",userModel.getName());
if(Mem_photobitmap!=null){

    UserObject.put("ProfilePicture",profilepicFile);
}
UserObject.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseException ex) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dismissProgressdialog();
        if (ex == null) {

            application.saveUser_UserName(userModel.getUsername());
            application.saveUser_Name(userModel.getName());
            application.savePassword(userModel.getPassword());
            application.saveUserEmail(userModel.getEmail());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signed Up Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

I searched and got the link [Parse file saveing error,""Unable to encode an unsaved parsefile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059943/parse-file-saveing-error-unable-to-encode-an-unsaved-parsefile)

I tried this code again , uploading first the profilepicture and then with ProgressCallback() i try to sign up but also got the same exception with this code

```
//first save profile pic to parse
if(Mem_photobitmap !=null){

    profilepicFile = userModel.getProfilePicture();
    profilepicFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {

            if(e!=null){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }      
        }
}, new ProgressCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(Integer arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // PrepareParseUser();
        final ParseUser UserObject = new ParseUser();
        UserObject.setUsername(userModel.getUsername());
        UserObject.setEmail(userModel.getEmail());
        UserObject.setPassword(userModel.getPassword());
        UserObject.put("Mobile_Number",userModel.getMobile_Number());
        UserObject.put("Name",userModel.getName());
        if(Mem_photobitmap!=null){

            UserObject.put("ProfilePicture",profilepicFile);
        }
        UserObject.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException ex) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dismissProgressdialog();
                if (ex == null) {

                    application.saveUser_UserName(userModel.getUsername());
                    application.saveUser_Name(userModel.getName());
                    application.savePassword(userModel.getPassword());
                    application.saveUserEmail(userModel.getEmail());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signed Up Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

any help please

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer
 i signed up to parse.com without profile picture then after finished update the user with profile picture

```
  showProgressdialog();
    final ParseUser UserObject = new ParseUser();
    UserObject.setUsername(userModel.getUsername());
    UserObject.setEmail(userModel.getEmail());
    UserObject.setPassword(userModel.getPassword());
    UserObject.put("Mobile_Number",userModel.getMobile_Number());
    UserObject.put("Name",userModel.getName());
    UserObject.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            if (ex == null) {                   
                if(Mem_photobitmap!=null){
                    application.saveUser_UserName(userModel.getUsername());
                    application.saveUser_Name(userModel.getName());
                    application.savePassword(userModel.getPassword());
                    application.saveUserEmail(userModel.getEmail());                        
                    UserObject.put("ProfilePicture", userModel.getProfilePicture());
                    UserObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {                            
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException ex) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            dismissProgressdialog();
                            if (ex == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signed Up Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }                               
                        }                        
                    });
                }else{
                    dismissProgressdialog();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signed Up Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }                   
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dismissProgressdialog();
            }
        }
    });
```